# Question about $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $G_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, proof-verification

For  $n ≥ 2$ we let $G_n ⊂ Z_n$ denote the
subset of all integers mod n which are invertible $\mod n$. Let $m, n \in 
\mathbb{Z}$ $m, n ≥ 2$ and $(m, n) = 1$. Deﬁne a mapping
$f : Z_m × Z_n → Z_{mn}$ as follows: set $f([a]_m, [b]_n) = [x]_n$ where $x$ is the
unique solution $(\mod mn)$ given by the Chinese Remainder Theorem to the
simultaneous linear congruences
$$[x]_m = [a]_m$$
$$[x]_n = [b]_n.$$
Show that $f$ is a bijective map. Show that $f(G_m × G_n) ⊂ G_{mn}$. Show
that $f : G_m × G_n −→ G_{mn}$ is bijective.

My attemps: pick $([a]_m, [b]_n),([a']_m, [b']_n) \in \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$ so that $f([a]_m, [b]_n) = [x]_n$ and $f([a']_m, [b']_n) = [x']_n$. If $[x]_n = [x']_n$, then by the definition of the map, we have that $[a]_m = [a']_m$ and $[b]_n = [b']_n$. Hence, $f$ is injective.

Now, take any $y \in \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$. Need to find a point $( \times  , \times)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$ so that $f( \times  , \times) = y = [x]_n$. By construction, we can just take $( \times  , \times) = ([a]_m,[b]_m)$. Hence, $f$ is surjective and therefore bijective.

Now, take $x \in f( G_m \times G_n) \implies x = [x]_n$ where $[x]_n$ is unique solution $\mod mn$ to $$[x]_m = [a]_m \in G_m$$
$$ [x]_n = [b]_n \in G_n$$

Therefore, $[x]_{mn} = [ab]_{mn} \in G_{mn}$. So, $x$ is unique solution to previous equation and hence $x$ lies in $G_{mn}$. therefore, $f(G_m × G_n) ⊂ G_{mn}$.

Is this correct? Also, is there a faster way to prove the last statement of the problem? can someone help me? I appreciate it, thanks

Comment: On the last part, it's not clear how you got $x = ab \pmod {mn}$ from $x = a \pmod m, x = b \pmod n$.

Comment: Can you help me fix this part? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\psi : \mathbb{Z}_{mn} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$ to be the opposite of your map $f$ and show that $\psi\circ f$ and $f \circ \psi$ are both $\rm id$.

Comment: But My solution to previous part is correct? can you give me some feedback? thanks